# How to construct array into a member variable (field)?

Tags: java, arrays

My `Array` class goes like this:

```
public class Array{

    public Array(double[] array){
        double[] x = new double[500];
    }    

    public double sum(){
        double sum = 0;
        double[] a = new double[500];
        for (double i : a) {
            sum += i;
        }
        return sum;
    }
}
```

There are lots of problem, but since I am a beginner, I really don't know how to fix them.

Original problem:

Write a class Array with a constructor and two methods:

Array(double[] array): constructor that stores array into a member variable (field).
double sum(): computes the sum of the elements stored in the array.
double average(): computes the average of the elements stored in the array.

Comment: What's `array` (the parameter) for?

Comment: You are misunderstanding the basics. What do you mean by "*construct array **into** a member*"? Please post your problems and try to be more specific. (do you mean `double[] x = array;`?)

Comment: You're not actually doing anything with the parameter variable array nor x. Also can you post more details about your problem, I can't understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: I posted the original problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hugo's answer gets to the general point, but missed the fact that you would be passing it in, and then storing it in a field:

```
public class Array {

    private final double[] array; //This is a field

    public Array(double[] array) {//Constructor, someone passed a double array in
        this.array = array; //Makes the field equivalent to the passed array
    }

    //Proceed to use "this.array" for access to the passed field

}
```

Another relatively more-advanced concept would be copying the values that are passed in to ensure that your class won't be mutated, but that's somewhat outside the scope of this question.

Comment: When I tried to submit, it showed    symptom: java.lang.NullPointerException
at Array.sum(Array.java:11)

Comment: public double sum(){
        double sum = 0;
        for (double i : this.array) {  //11
            sum += i;
        }
        return sum;
    }

Comment: @Zooey mind updating your question with the code you currently are using? My only thought would be that you didn't initialize something.

Comment: Oh, I figure out now. I didn't consider the condition that if this.array == null. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You're not definining a class field anywhere. I guess this is what you want to do:

```
public class Array{

    private double[] x;

    public Array(){ //notice that you weren't using the parameter here
        x = new double[500];
    }    

    public double sum(){

        double sum = 0;
        for (double i : x) {
            sum += i;
        }
        return sum;
    }
}
```

Notice that you don't have a method to add elements to the `Array` so far, so you'll have an empty array `x`, and sum will obviously return 0.

Answer (score 0):

Are you just saying you want double[] x to be a field in your class?  If so, take the declaration out of the constructor and put it above that.
i.e.

```
public class Array{

    double [] x;
    public Array(double[] array){
        x = array;
    }  
....
}
```

Then initialize the array when you create an instance of the class;

```
new Array(new double[500]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public class Array{

    private double[] x;//instance variable, the field you are missing

    public Array(double[] array){
        x = array;//initialize with constructor argument
    }    

    public double sum(){
        double sum = 0;
        for (double i : x) {//use the same field, you were creating a new one
            sum += i;
        }
        return sum;
    }

    public double average(){//your code was missing this method as well
        return sum() / x.length;
    }
}
```